# I need to take arguments from the user instead of hard coding in commands to execute concurrently using fork()

Tags: c, fork, exec

I have created a simple code block below which forks from the parent, and executes "ls" and "date" concurrently:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    cpid1, cpid2;

    switch(cpid1 = fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("fork failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        case 0:
            printf("First child, pid=%d, executing ls...\n", getpid());
            execl("/bin/ls", "-l", "-a", NULL);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    switch(cpid2 = fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("fork failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        case 0:
            printf("Second child, pid=%d, executing ls...\n", getpid());
            execl("/bin/date", "-l", "-a", NULL);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(wait(NULL) != -1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I don't want to run "ls" and "date" every time as seen in the 2 execl statements. I want the user to be able to enter up to 6 commands delimited by commas. I think I should be doing something like execl("argv[1]", NULL) but I'm at wits end

Comment: The function you're looking for is `execvp`. You can use `strtok` to split the user's input into separate commands using the comma as a delimiter, and then use `strtok` on each command to separate the command and the arguments using whitespace as the delimiter.

Comment: It'll be easier if you don't use commas. If you just use spaces then you can use `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc directly. Then call `execvp`.

Comment: Will execvp search for the command they enter, such as pwd for example? How would it do that?

Comment: Yes `execvp` will search for the command. It uses the PATH environment variable, or a built-in search path if PATH is not set.

Comment: I was looking at the manual for it, and you're exactly right that sounds like the best course of action. Do you have any recommendations on how to split up command line arguments so I know only things in between commas are what I want?

Comment: ^Specifically when it comes to using the args as argv[] for execvp. For example if I say "./assignment.c  ls -a , pwd , cat example.txt" how would execvp know that -a is part of ls, and similarly know that pwd has nothing to do with ls or -a